# Getting all registered instances of own MBean

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

I have register my MBean app this way:

```
ObjectName appName = new ObjectName("testpack.Application:name=myApp");
MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
mbs.registerMBean(this, appName);
```

And next I'm trying to get all registered instances by:

```
for (ObjectInstance instance : mbs.queryMBeans(appName, null)) {
    System.out.println(instance.toString());
}
```

But this prints only one instance even if I run many instances of this same app on this same JVM. What I misunderstood? How to do this properly?

---

### EDIT

Excuse me, I misunderstood some basic terms like MBeans, JMX agents, servers and clients. Now I now that my app must be an JMX client and expose common MBean to do some kind of communication across my apps and maybe own managment console in future.

@Gray point me that I'm asking about some different that I want. Now I'm study JMX from basics and some aspects was clearly.

Comment: I don't understand how you can run multiple "instances of the same app" in the same JVM.  Is that a typo?  Or are you saying that you have multiple _classes_ in the same app?

Comment: By typing `java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -jar TestApp.jar` twice in cmdprompt... I have two running instances, this was typo.

Comment: Please edit your question then.  So you are accessing the `MBeanServer` of the JVM you are running in with the code in the post, right?  To connect to a remote JMX server you are going to have to use a JMX client.  Is that what you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

So now it seems that you are talking about multiple JVMs running on a box.  By using the `ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer()` code, you are accessing the beans in the current JVM *only*.  If you are trying to look at beans on another JVM instance then you are going to have to use a JMX client to connect to that remote process.  Using my [SimpleJMX](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/) package you could do something like:

```
JmxClient client = new JmxClient("localhost", somePortNumber);
Set<ObjectName> objectNameSet = client.getBeanNames();
...
```

Here are the [javadocs for my JmxClient](http://256stuff.com/sources/simplejmx/javadoc/simplejmx/com/j256/simplejmx/client/JmxClient.html).  There are certainly others clients that do this.  Java 6+ might even have them built in.  I know that there are ways to programmatically list the JVM instances on the current computer in Java 6+.  My SimpleJMX package does not do that.

---

I'm not sure I understand the question but I think you are saying that you have multiple instances of your `myApp` class but you are only seeing one of them in JMX.

You are going to have to create unique `ObjectName` for each of your classes if you want to see them separately via JMX.  Typically, we use folders and bean names (sometimes even `System.identityHashCode(obj)`) to get a unique name for each instance of the object.

For example, we have a large number of timer factory beans.  They have object names like:

```
mprew:00=timers,name=MailServerTimerFactory
mprew:00=timers,name=MysqlManagerTimerFactory
mprew:00=timers,name=PointsTimerFactory
```

They all are the same class and we are using the spring bean to identify them specifically.

Comment: I'm not using spring. So, if I have first instance with `ObjectName("testpack.Application:name=a")` and second with `ObjectName("testpack.Application:name=b")` then how to query its instances?

Comment: The answer depends on if there are in the same JVM or now @kbec.  I've edited my answer if you are talking about 2 different JVMs.